# Setting word table border from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, border

I am having trying to set border of word table from Excel VBA. Many sites suggest the following:

```
wrdTable.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
```

but I get an error (The requested member of the collection does not exist) while trying it. However, I could bring inner borders using following code:

```
wrdTable.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Similarly I tried:

```
wrdTable.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

to bring top borders, but I get diagonal lines. How could I apply borders (inner and outside borders) in my word tables? I am using office 2007.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These articles will put you on the right track:

http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/formatting/border-basics.html

http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/styles/borders-in-table-styles.html

Assuming your `wrdTable` is properly set to the table object in msword's document you have a few options:

```
wrdTable.Borders.Enable = True
```

Setting this to True set's the object's borders to the same line style and line width as the current default border properties for this object.

Otherwise guidelines are

- Set the .LineStyle first.
- Only if .LineStyle is not wdLineStyleNone then

  - set the .LineWidth
  - set the .Color.

Heres a more detailed version:

```
With wrdTable.Borders
    .OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt
    .OutsideColor = wdDarkRed
End With
```

For additional reference on syntax, see this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221392(v=office.11).aspx

(note, I've typed this code from my mobile phone, so it is untested)

Comment: These trifle things wouldn't bother much if there had been good intellisense in the IDE. Any suggestions for the list of all objects and properties.

Comment: Out of interest do you mean wdColorDarkRed rather than wdDarkRed?

Answer (score 2):

Select in "Microsoft Visual Basic" the menu "Tools" -> "References" and activate "Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library".
Then

```
wrdTable.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
```

will work.

I was also searching for the same function for hours.